# Multiple Path Params in Jersey

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm building my first rest api webservice and now i want to get two different path params, but it is not working!

here's the code that is causing the error:

```
@PUT 
@Path("/{projectid}/updateproject/{profileid}") 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Projects updateProject(
        @PathParam("projectid") int projectid, 
        @PathParam("profileid") int profileid, 
        Projects pProject,
        Profiles pProfile) {  
    pProject.setProjektid(projectid); 
    pProfile.setPersonalnummer(profileid);
    return service.addProfileInProject(pProject, pProfile); 
}
```

And this is the error i get:
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization. 
It also says something with: 
on resource class ... contains multiple parameters with no annotation. Unable to resolve the injection source.

Please help me with this issue! 
Thanks! <3

Comment: You sure you're using the [JAX-RS annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html) and not the [websocket one](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/PathParam.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I'm using the JAX-RS annotation

Comment: Because you have two entity objects (Projects and Profiles). You can only have one. Has nothing to do with the PathParams

Comment: But i need both of them.., Is there a way to have more than one?

Comment: Combine it into one object.

Comment: Nevermind just fixed it!